# Which way of processing data in pandas dataframe is faster?

Tags: python, pandas, performance, dataframe

I need to create a dataframe in Python using pandas. For each observation, I need to download the data using requests. I am thinking two possible ways to generate the dataframe.

Option 1. Download observation data one by one. After each observation is downloaded, I extract the data and do some calculation on the data. Then, insert the data into a dataframe.

Option 2. Download all observation data using threading and create a dataframe including all data (including the ones I don't need). Then, extract and do calculations on all observations in dataframe.

My questions are: would Option 2 be faster than Option 1? Would Option 2 occupy more memory than Option 1 during the process?

Any alternative suggestions are appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I think it really depends on the file sizes and the what you are trying to accomplish. I've used both methods. Try profiling the memory with a small set of files. https://pypi.org/project/memory-profiler/

Comment: The entire data set (including unneeded data) can be around 2gb.